# jQuery plugin for DataTable doesn't work. fnGetColumnData

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I added plugin

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData
```

Can be found here: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api

After I executed

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var oDataTable = $("#usersGrid").dataTable();
//... 
}
```

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property
>   'asSorting': object is null or undefined.

What can be a reason? 
P.S.: It's not fnGetColumnData problem but another one which connected with `$("#usersGrid").dataTable();`

```
$('#example').dataTable({
            "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip<',
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "A" },
                { "sTitle": "B" },
                { "sTitle": "C" }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us the markup of your table?If you don't provide a valid table with headers dataTables has problems

Comment: look at this : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6246/asp.net-dynamic-data-website-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error/p1 might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this has something to do with your markup. Remember that dataTables needs an html table with `<thead>` section with a `<th>` for each column. If you are trying to initialize an empty table you should try

```
$('#usersGrid').dataTable({
  aoData: [{}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true that dataTables need an html table with `<thead>` and a `<th>` for each column.  An easier fix however, is to simply add the following line in the code behind, immediately after the `databind()` call.

```
MyGridView.DataSource = <some data source>
MyGridView.DataBind();
MyGridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; // wraps header row with THEAD element for sorting
```